# wire function not working in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

```
  @wire(getCampaignList, {}) campaignLst; - working
   @wire(getLeadRecordType, {}) recType;
   @wire(getAccount, {}) acc;
   @wire(getLOwner, {}) ldOwner; 

    alert(this.acc.data); - undefined
```

campaign list is working for other 3 are not any ideas?

UPDate

---

```
public with sharing class LeadController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Campaign> getCampaignNames(){
        List<Campaign> options = new List<Campaign>();
        try {
           options = [SELECT id, Name FROM Campaign ];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return options;
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getLeadOwner(){
       User u=  [SELECT id FROM User WHERE name='Advisor' LIMIT 1];
        return u.id;
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getDealerAccount(){
       Account dAcc =  [SELECT id FROM Account WHERE name='New Account'];
        return dAcc.id;
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getLeadRecordType(){
        Id residRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Resid').getRecordTypeId();
        return residRecordTypeId;
    }


}
```

```
import { LightningElement,track,wire} from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import LEAD_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/Lead";
import getLOwner from '@salesforce/apex/LeadController.getLeadOwner';
// import getContactList from '@salesforce/apex/LeadController.getContactList';
import getCampaignList from '@salesforce/apex/LeadController.getCampaignNames';
import getLeadRecordType from '@salesforce/apex/LeadController.getLeadRecordType';
import getDealerAccount from '@salesforce/apex/LeadController.getDealerAccount';

export default class LeadIntakeForm extends LightningElement {  
    leadRecord = {};
    @track contacts;
    @track value;
    map = new Map(); 
   @wire(getCampaignList, {}) campaignLst;
   @wire(getLeadRecordType, {}) recType;
   @wire(getDealerAccount, {}) dealerAcc;
   @wire(getLOwner, {}) ldOwner; 
    
    get campaignOptions() {
        return this.campaignLst.data?.map(
            ({ Id, Name }) => ({ value: Id, label: Name })
          );
      }

    handleChange(event) {
            this.leadRecord[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    }
     

   createLead() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    const fields = this.leadRecord;
    fields.RecordTypeId=JSON.stringify(this.recType.data);
    fields.Status= "Marketing Qualified";
        fields.Dealer_Locator_Selection__c = JSON.stringify(this.dealerAcc);

    alert(fields.Dealer_Locator_Selection__c);
    //fields.CurrencyIsoCode= "USD - U.S.Dollar"; NOT WORKING
    fields.Theater__c="North America";

    fields.LeadSource ="Web";
    fields.Country = 'US';
    fields.MobilePhone = this.leadRecord["Phone"];
    fields.OwnerId=this.getLOwner.data;
    console.log(' fields.OwnerId' +  fields.OwnerId);
    var objRecordInput = {'apiName' : 'Lead', fields};
    

    createRecord(objRecordInput)
    .then(response => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: "Success",
                message: " Lead created successfully! " + response.id,
                variant: "success"
            })
        );
    }).catch(error => {
       alert('Error: ' +JSON.stringify(error));
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: "Error creating record",
                message: error,
                variant: "error"
            })
        );
    
    }).finally(() => {
            this.isLoading = false;
        }
    );
   
} 
}
```

---

Comment: Can you paste the complete code?

Comment: @Mentee Can you add more info in your question? Add minimal required code? What error is coming? Where are you using it? How you have written your apex method?

Comment: Context is important. Keep in mind that wire methods run asynchronously, so they won't be available early in the component life cycle.

Comment: @sfdcfox I getting the record type to saved the the record it was working before suddenly stopped working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to consider.

#### Wire Method

Sometimes is better to use `wire method` instead of `wire property`.

```js
@wire(getCampaignList, {})
wiredAccount({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
         this.campaignOptions = data?.map(
            ({ Id, Name }) => ({ value: Id, label: Name })
         );
    } else if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

**Why?**

- wire is asynchronous, you can wait for a response by doing it in this way.
- it's easier to figure out what a problem is by `console.error`/debugging.

#### LWC API

You can use `uiObjectInfoApi` to get RecordTypeId.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info

```js
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
wiredAccount({ error, data }) {
    if (!data) {
        return;
    }

    this.residRecordTypeId = Object.keys(data.recordTypeInfos)
                                   .find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'Resid');
};
```