# MALFORMED_ID- unable to resolve

Tags: lightning-web-components, sales

Image2

[image]

Image1

[image]

I am trying to create a Lead record and when I click submit I am getting this error. Dealer_locator_selection__c is account field lookup on lead. any inputs please?

you can find the code below link
[wire function not working in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/388315/wire-function-not-working-in-lwc/388330#388330).

I tired doing this, still it did not resolve the issue

```
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getDealerAccount(){
       Account dAcc =  [SELECT id FROM Account WHERE name='newAcc'];
        return String.valueOf(dAcc.id).subString(0, 15);
    }
```

Comment: Please include all of the relevant information and logs in your question _as text_, not as images. You can do this in an [edit]. Thanks!

Comment: @david-reed This is all I have. Please let me know if you need me to add debugs

Comment: @DavidReed can you paste code where you are creating lead. And field type of Dealer Selection as well

Comment: @prajjwalagrawal I have added a link in which i have complete code

Comment: @Mentee I am asking you to include your debug logs/error messages as text, not as images. I'm not asking you to add anything new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding,instead of fields.Dealer_Locator_Selection__c = JSON.stringify(this.dealerAcc.data)

Use

```
fields.Dealer_Locator_Selection__c = this.dealerAcc.data;
```

Because this is already string and once your are again stringify it. It will add quotes as well.

Comment: @prajjwalagarwal you are right. it worked!